# Copying a html page with fopen and having a check on the new page to look for session variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page that uses session variables and sql polling to dynamically populate divs etc for the process of live editing, I then need to be able to publish the same page with these variables hardcoded into the page. To do this I have copied the html using fopen to create a new page. This works but with a few annoyances or limitations. Because the source page code doesnt show show up the php code the fopen cannot copy it so I cannot use php to check if there is a session id. I was hoping to use the fact that there is no php on the newly created page that would allow me to check for a session id and if there was none, to hide certain elements on the newly created page. Some of the solutions I have looked at are as follows.

1/ Get jquery to check for php tags and if there are none hide the divs I need to hide.
      Result: Cannot find any code that may suggest how to do this

2/ fopen just the html in that I need to display the info I require and amend into another template.
      Result: fseek could have helped in inserting the copied html into a specific line pointed to by fseek, however one of the divs being copied has a length of input text that is going to be variable in length and as I understand it if the input extends the copied code beyond 1 line it could overwrite other code. Also I dont have necassary knowledge to facilitate this if it is possible

The elements I need to hide are a button that opens up a editing menu, and the editing menu itself.

**The full code of dynamic page (Split into 3, with the middle section I want to hide**

```
<?php
include_once '../../../includes/db_connect.php';
include_once '../../../includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);



$first_name = $_SESSION['memberInfo']['memberFirstName'];
$surname = $_SESSION['memberInfo']['memberLastName'];
$hash = $_SESSION['memberInfo']['hash'];
$newTemplateSrc = $_SESSION['memberInfo']['templateSrc'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE firstName = '$first_name' AND surName = '$surname' AND passWord = '$hash'";

$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
        $dateofBirth = $row['dateofBirth'];
        $deceasedName = $row['deceasedName'];
        $dateofDeath = $row['dateofDeath'];
        $aboutDeceased = $row['aboutDescription'];
        $directoryId = $row['directoryid'];
        $templateFileSrc = $row['templateFileSrc'];
        $deceasedImage = $row['deceasedPhoto'];
};
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>RIDERS in the SKY CREATE MEMORIAL</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../style/rits2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../Valums-File-Uploader-file-uploader-9991748/client/fileuploader.css">

<style type="text/css">
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(135,206,235,1);
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(135,206,235,1);
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgba(135,206,235,1);
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <table id="head_top">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="10%" rowspan="3" class="logo"><a href="../../../index.html" target="_self"><img src="../../../images/riders-in-the-sky.png" alt="RIDERS IN THE SKY LOGO - CLICKING HERE TAKES YOU TO THE HOME PAGE" title="RIDERS IN THE SKY LOGO - CLICKING HERE TAKES YOU TO THE HOME PAGE" class="logo_image"/></a></td>
          <td width="80%" colspan="3" class="title">RIDERS IN THE SKY </td>
          <td width="10%" rowspan="3" class="login_register"><table class="log_nav">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td><form action="../../../register.php"><input name="register" type="submit" class="register"  title="REGISTER HERE" id="register" value="Register"></form></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><form action="../../../login.php"><input name="login" type="submit" class="login" title="LOGIN HERE" id="login" value="Login"></form>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr> </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="title_tagline">MEMORIALS AND FUNERAL RESOURCES FOR BIKERS AND MOTORCYCLISTS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="3but_nav volunteer"><a href="../../../volunteer.php" title="VOLUNTERR HERE">VOLUNTEER</a></div></td>
          <td><div class="3but_nav resource hover"><a href="../../../resources.php" title="FIND FUNERAL RESOURCES HERE">FUNERAL RESOURCES</a></div></td>
          <td><div class="3but_nav about"><a href="../../../about.php" title="FIND OUT MORE ABOUT RIDERSin the SKY HERE">ABOUT US</a></div></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="top_nav">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="create"><form><input name="create" type="button" class="create_but" id="create" value="Create Memorial" title="CTREATE A MEMORIAL HERE" onClick="window.location.href='../../../create.php'"></form></td>
          <td class="view"><form><input name="view" type="button" class="view_but" id="view" value="View Memorials" title="VIEW A MEMORIAL HERE" onClick="window.location.href='../../../view.php'"></form></td>
          <td class="faq"><form><input name="faq" type="button" class="faq_but" id="faq" value="Faq's" title="GO TO OUR FAQ's and HELP PAGE" onClick="window.location.href='../../../faq.php'"></form></td>
          <td class="contact"><form><input name="contact" type="button" class="contact_but" id="contact" value="Contact Us" title="NEED TO CONTACT US? CONTACT US HERE" onClick="window.location.href='../../../contact.php'"></form></td>
          <td class="donate"><form><input name="donate" type="button" class="donate_but" id="donate" value="Make a Donation" title="WANT TO MAKE A DONATION TO RIDERSin the SKY? GO TO OUR DONATIONS PAGE" onClick="window.location.href='../../../donation.php'"></form></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </header>
  <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="content_main" -->
 <main class="content">
<section>
    <div id="deceasedName" class="#" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $deceasedName ?></div>
    <div id="DeceasedDetail" contenteditable="false">
    <div id="dob" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $dateofBirth ?></div>
    <div id="deceasedImage" contenteditable="false"><img class="deceasedImage" src="<?php echo $deceasedImage ?>"></div>
    <div id="dod" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $dateofDeath ?></div>
    <div id="deceasedProfile">
    <h1 id="aboutTitle" contenteditable="false" >About <?php  echo $deceasedName?></h1>
    <h2 id="aboutDesciption" contenteditable="false" ><?php echo $aboutDeceased ?></h2>  
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Area of code I want to hide**

```
  <input id="editMemorial" name="button" type="button" class="editMemorial" value="Edit/Create Memorial">



  <div id="editMenu" class="editMenu" style="display:none">
    <button id="editDOB" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add D.O.B</button>
    <button id="editPic" class="editMenuNav">Change/Add Deceased Photo</button>
    <button id="editDOD" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add Deceased D.O.D</button>
    <button id="editDeceasedTitle" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add About the Deceased Title</button>
    <button id="editDeceasedDescription" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add About the Deceased</button>    
    <button id="editName" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add Deceased Name</button>
    <button id="saveEdits" class="editMenuNav">Save Changes</button>      
  </div>  





  </main>
```

**Rest of the html code**

```
 <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="breadcrumb">
      <p class="breadcrumb"><a href="../../../resources.php">Funeral Resources</a> | <a href="../../../terms.php">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="../../../privacy.php">Privacy</a> | <a href="../../../about.php">About Us</a> | <a href="../../../contact.php">Contact Us</a> | <a href="../../../faq.php">Faq's</a></p>
      <p class="copyright"><span>©2015 RIDERS IN THE SKY</span></p>
    </div>
</footer>



</div>


<div id="uploadDeceasedImage" style="display: none">
  <div class="uploadText">Due to a limitation in the upload image code<br>Once you have uploaded the Deceased Photo the page will refresh automatically.<br>This will regretably mean you will need to click on the 'Edit/Create Memorial' button to complete editing the text on the memorial page.</div>
  <div id="closeDeceasedUpload">Close Upload X</div>
<noscript>          
  <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
     or put a simple form for upload here 
</noscript> 
    <div id="preview">
<img src="../../../images/riders in the sky no text.png" alt="" width="100px" height="100px" class="deceasedThumb"/>
    </div>

<!--<form id="deceasedImageUpload">
        <label class="deceasupload">Upload a Picture of the Deceased</label>
        <input type="file" size="20" id="imageUpload" class=" ">
        <button type="submit" class="saveDeceasedImage">Save Photo</button>
</form>-->
<div id="uploadDeceasedImageWrapper">
</div>




        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple style="display:none">
        <input type="button" id="upload_but" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')" style="display: none" value="Upload Images">





</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../Valums-File-Uploader-file-uploader-9991748/client/fileuploader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".editMemorial").on('click', function() {
    $('.editMenu').show();
    $('.editMemorial').hide();  
});

$("#saveEdits").on('click', function() {

    var dateofBirth = ($('#dob').text());
    var deceasedName = ($('#deceasedName').text());
    var dateofDeath = ($('#dod').text());
    var aboutTitle = ($('#aboutTitle').text());
    var aboutDescription = ($('#aboutDesciption').text());  
    var firstName = ("<?php echo $first_name?>");
    var surName = ("<?php echo $surname?>");
    var hash = ("<?php echo $hash?>");
    var templateSrc = ("<?php echo $newTemplateSrc?>");


//  console.log(dateofBirth, deceasedName, dateofDeath, abouttheDeceased,firstName, surName, hash, templateSrc);

    $.post('../../../includes/editContent.php', {dateofBirth:dateofBirth,deceasedName:deceasedName,dateofDeath:dateofDeath, aboutTitle:aboutTitle,aboutDescription:aboutDescription,firstName:firstName,surName:surName,hash:hash,templateSrc:templateSrc }, function(json) {

    if(json.result === "success") {



    $('.editMenu').hide();
    $('.editMemorial').show();
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');      
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#')
    $('#dod').attr('class','#')
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#')
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#')      
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#')
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();

    }else{



            };



    });//json call
});//onclick

// editable clicks
$("#editDOB").on('click', function() {
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','deceasedNameHighlight');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#');
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();               
});

$("#editName").on('click', function() {
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','deceasedNameHighlight');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#');
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();       
});

$("#editDOD").on('click', function() {
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'true');  
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','deceasedNameHighlight');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#');
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();       
});

$("#editDeceasedDescription").on('click', function() {
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','deceasedNameHighlight');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#'); 
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();           
});

$("#editDeceasedTitle").on('click', function() {
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'true');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','deceasedNameHighlight');
    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();           
});

$('#editPic').on('click', function() {

    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').show();
        $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#');

});

$('#closeDeceasedUpload').on('click', function() {  

    $('#uploadDeceasedImage').hide();
    $('#dob').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#dod').attr('contenteditable', 'false'); 
    $('#deceasedName').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('contenteditable', 'false');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('contenteditable', 'false');

    $('#dob').attr('class','#');
    $('#dod').attr('class','#');
    $('#deceasedName').attr('class','#');               
    $('#aboutDesciption').attr('class','#');
    $('#aboutTitle').attr('class','#');

    location.reload();

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        // DOM-ready event is a much option here, just using onload in demo for simplicity
        // jQuery users can use $(function()) { ...
        window.onload = function() {

            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({

                // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
                element: document.getElementById('uploadDeceasedImageWrapper'),

                // path to server-side upload script
                // action: '/server/upload'
                action: '../../../includes/uploadDeceased_image.php',
                     params: {
                                directoryId: '<?php echo $directoryId ?>',
                                templateSrc: '<?php echo $templateFileSrc ?>'
                             },         

                allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
                sizeLimit: 100000000,   // 100mb
                minSizeLimit: 500,

                debug: true
            }); 
        };

    </script>


   <script type="text/javascript">

   $('#saveEdits').on('click', function() {
       var html = $("html").html();
       var fileName = <?php echo $directoryId  ?>;
       console.log(html);
       $.post('../../../includes/memorialSave.php', {html:html, fileName:fileName}, function(json)  {
           $(".editMenu").hide();
           $(".editMemorial").show();
       });




   });
   </script>
```

I realise that my jquery is long winded but 1/ I'm new to jquery and am aware that there are better ways to write the jquery, I just wanted stuff to work, so no need to comment on this.

Comment: You're trying to do this on the client? The client never sees PHP code, it just gets the output of the PHP script. Session variables only exist on the server, they're not in the page that's sent to the client. I'm not even sure what session variables have to do with this, since there aren't any in the section you want to hide.

Comment: @Barmar As I mentioned in my question I realise the php isnt seen by the client, however if there is a way that jquery could look for php tags or the lact of a php session and then not finding any then hide the two elements, ie; 'if there are no php sessions or variables,  or there are no php tags then hide elemement'

Comment: jQuery runs on the client, so it can't look for PHP tags. There's no way for it to tell anything about PHP sessions.

Comment: So all you can do in jQuery is `$("#editMemorial, #editMenu").hide()`.

Comment: @Barmar I would have done that, but that will hide the elements on the editing page making them unobtainable for the editing process

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this on the client. Do it on the server. When it's creating an editing page, it sends those elements, when it's creating a published page it doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar I'm doing the fopen and fwrite in the server process, but this only copies the html of the page which is the client so anything I need in the new page has to exsist on the original page, unless there is a way to facilitate this on the server process somehow that I'm not aware of

Comment: @Barmar, sorry misread your last comment, yes that makes sense can you suggest how I might do that please, would it help if I put the processing pages in the question although that may not be appreciated with all the code involved

Answer (score 0):

When you're publishing, pass a URL parameter that says so, e.g. `scriptname.php?publish=yes`. Then in the PHP code, you can do:

```
$publish = isset($_GET['publish']) ? $_GET['publish'] == 'yes' : false;
if (!$publish) {
    ?>
      <input id="editMemorial" name="button" type="button" class="editMemorial" value="Edit/Create Memorial">



      <div id="editMenu" class="editMenu" style="display:none">
        <button id="editDOB" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add D.O.B</button>
        <button id="editPic" class="editMenuNav">Change/Add Deceased Photo</button>
        <button id="editDOD" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add Deceased D.O.D</button>
        <button id="editDeceasedTitle" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add About the Deceased Title</button>
        <button id="editDeceasedDescription" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add About the Deceased</button>    
        <button id="editName" class="editMenuNav">Edit/Add Deceased Name</button>
        <button id="saveEdits" class="editMenuNav">Save Changes</button>      
      </div>  
    <?php
}
```